# Cannot enter value into field with react-hook-form and react-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, input, frontend, react-hook-form

I encountered an issue with `react-places-autocomplete` library. I use it with `react-hook-form`. The input is MUI `TextField` component. I register value with 'register' function of `react-hook-form` in the `TextField`. The `TextField` is inside `PlacesAutocomplete` component (default import from `react-places-autocomplete` library).

`onChange` property of `PlacesAutocomplete` component gets the function where I call `setValue` function from `react-hook-form` to set entered value. This value should update the `TextField` but it doesn't. Also when I call `react-places-autocomplete` `getValue('address')` function, I get object `{ address: '' }` even though a lot of characters have been entered.

The main problem is that locally everything works (with running `'react-scripts start'` script) and when I enter value into `TextField`, it updates and when I call `getValue('address')` I get object `{ address: enteredValue }`. But in deployed version (built with `'npm install && yarn install && yarn build'`) I cannot enter anything with the same codebase. Could you, please, help me with this problem?

`LocationSearchInput` component:

```
<PlacesAutocomplete
  value={address}
  onChange={handleChangeAddress}
  onSelect={handleSelect}
>
  {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
    <div>
      <CustomTextField
        {...register('address', {
          value: defaultAddress || '',
        })}
        {...getInputProps({
          label: (
            <FormattedMessage
              id="required"
              defaultMessage="{text}*"
              values={{
                text: (
                  <FormattedMessage
                    id="enter_address"
                    defaultMessage="Enter address"
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />
          ),
          fullWidth: true,
          className: 'location-search-input',
          error,
          helperText,
        })}
      />
      <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">...</div>
    </div>
  </PlacesAutocomplete>
```

`handleChangeAddress` function:

```
const handleChangeAddress = async (addr) => {
   setValue('address', addr, { shouldTouch: true })
   await trigger('address')
   if (!addr) {
      setValue('city', '', { shouldTouch: true })
      await trigger('city')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mui inputs are controlled. You should use `useController` from `react-hook-form` instead of `register(...)`

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller